# Changing 'thickness' of bootstrap list-group-item

Tags: css, listitem, thickness

I want to reduce how thick the list-group-item are, whilst keeping the title text fitting.

```
<ul class="list-group"> 
  <a href="#id" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-toggle="collapse">Title</a>
</ul>

.list-group-item {
  height: 10px;
}
```

This successfully reduces the thickness, but the Title text remains too big. I suspect height is the wrong property to use?

[image: text too big]

Comment: try changing the `font-size` of the link

Comment: Tried that, the font size reduces but it remains in the wrong position.

Comment: add `line-height` as well and mess around with the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size is controlled by this class

```
.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 15px; /* adjust here */
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    line-height: 1em /* set to text height */
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/avOLRq)

Answer (score 1):

`li` tags have a default padding. You must to reset it to achieve it. The text have a `line-height` defined relative to his size. You must to define the `line-height` as equal as `height`.

```
  li {
    padding:0;
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't do that instead use padding like this..

```
ul a {
padding:10px; // give padding
height:auto;
}
```